# Inserting an image into a Google Docs document from a Google Forms response sheet using placeholders

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, placeholder

I am quite new to coding as a whole and do not have much experience with Javascript, i am trying to insert an image from my Google Forms response page (which inputs it as a drive link e.g "https://drive.google.com/file/d/17mMFxpUv1s9wI0mixQMKXQd6ojWaamJb/view")

Here is my code as of now.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var formId = '17pmzdoPjnw_yztuRkEdaoAokxLTlbKyAibN5-_nGN-k'; 
  var form = FormApp.openById(formId);
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var latestResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1];
  var itemResponses = latestResponse.getItemResponses();

  var formData = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    var question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var response = itemResponse.getResponse();
    formData[question] = response;
  }

  var firstName = formData['First Name'];
  var surname = formData['Surname'];

  // Get the current timestamp
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(latestResponse.getTimestamp(), 'GMT', 'dd/MM/yyyy');

  // Specify the Google Docs template file ID
  var templateFileId = '1YX6D2j97TcC4T8Z_32G5Fehyf4xvoaEBs7mI5nwl0a0';

  var destinationFolderId = '17PLrLo19QUQNTq2o-QzXkM0EutSHN-XO'; // Replace with your Destination Folder ID

  // Make a copy of the template file
  var copiedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(templateFileId).makeCopy();

  // Move the copied file to the destination folder
  DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId).addFile(copiedFile);

  // Get the destination document ID
  var destinationFileId = copiedFile.getId();

  // Open the destination document
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(destinationFileId);

  // Replace placeholders in the document with form response data
  for (var field in formData) {
    var value = formData[field];
    doc.getBody().replaceText("{{" + field + "}}", value);
  }

  // Replace the {{Timestamp}} placeholder with the actual timestamp
  doc.getBody().replaceText('{{Timestamp}}', timestamp);

  // Save and close the document
  doc.saveAndClose();

  // Rename the document
  var destinationFile = DriveApp.getFileById(destinationFileId);
  var newName = firstName + ' ' + surname;
  destinationFile.setName(newName);

  // Log the new file name for verification
  Logger.log('Renamed file to: ' + newName);
}
```

This handles the placeholders perfectly but does not work with the images.

Some side information

The header is "Photograph Card" and the placeholder is "{{Photograph Card}}"

Currently the placeholder is just outputting the file ID "17mMFxpUv1s9wI0mixQMKXQd6ojWaamJb" as an example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks,

I have tried the code i mentioned above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I script a photo from Google Form upload and set its size to 1 inch for display in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930141/how-do-i-script-a-photo-from-google-form-upload-and-set-its-size-to-1-inch-for-d)