# Is there an apps script to find and replace text with an image?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm very new to programming languages in general, I learned basic html in highschool and that's about it. I'm trying to replace page breaks in a book from '**' to a png file of flourish but it's long enough half of the first chapter has taken me an hour and a half. At this point I feel lik I'm too far in to give up now.

Every script I can find seems like it has a totally different format for each one or it's for google sheets rather than docs.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: No problem! I'm sturggling with the formatting for a find and replace script but rather than replacing with a specified text I need it to replace with a png

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your question from `I'm sturggling with the formatting for a find and replace script but rather than replacing with a specified text I need it to replace with a png`. In order to correctly understand the current issue of your script and your goal, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi. I _think_ I understand your scenario but I would like to be crystal clear about what you are doing and the desired outcome. Please correct me if I am wrong. You have a Google Doc containing content. Within the content, page breaks are identified by `**` (i.e. two asterisks, no single or double quotes, possibly but not necessarily include a hidden carriage return). You want to substitute each `**` with a specific png file. Would you please advise the location of the PNG (local, Google Drive, internet, etc). Would you please supply a short sample document for testing.

Comment: Have you read [How do I script a photo from Google Form upload and set its size to 1 inch for display in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65008724/1330560)? I've used this to replace placeholders (such as `**`) in a Google Doc with a given image.