# Insert Image From Drive To Table in Google Document With Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a master document, where I want to change the contents of the document, including replacing certain text with images that I have in Drive.

To replace text, there is no problem, but I have difficulty when replacing Text in a table with an image that I have.

```
  function insertImage( ) {

  var image   = DriveApp.getFileById('1h293aKzW97sFqzRtREHp3hO_KV8czgKI').getBlob();  
  var copyId  = DriveApp.getFileById('1dY0-q_W-YO_R6WoOE6BqueN9qGFS06TPyrGWGeqChfY')
           .makeCopy('Application'+'_2020-')
           .getId();

 // get the body 
 var copyBody = DocumentApp.openById(copyId).getBody();

// find the position where to add the image
var position = copyBody.findText('<<MY IMAGE>>').getElement();
var offset = copyBody.getChildIndex(position.getParent())

// add the image below and resize it

var insertedImage = copyBody.insertImage(offset + 1,image).setHeight(100).setWidth(100)

// align it to the right 

var styles = {};
styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = 
DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
insertedImage.getParent().setAttributes(styles)

// remove the keyphoto placeholder text
position.removeFromParent()
}
```

I use that script from this [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930141/how-do-i-script-a-photo-from-google-form-upload-and-set-its-size-to-1-inch-for-d)
After Excecution,  I have error notification :
***Error**

Exception: Element does not contain the specified child element.*

I want to insert image to the table with replace Text **MY IMAGE** and place to the table :
[image]

*I am greatful for any help.*

Comment: As a guess. The script searches for `<<MY IMAGE>>` but the document contains just `MY IMAGE` without `<<>>`. You have either change `MY IMAGE` to `<<MY IMAGE>>` in the document or change in the code to: `findText('MY IMAGE')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

I thought that when I saw your showing script and your showing sample template Document, there were 2 modification points.

1. In your script, a text of `<<MY IMAGE>>` is used as the search text. But, in your showing template document, `<<MY IMAGE>>` is not used. It seems that `MY IMAGE` is used. In this case, `<<MY IMAGE>>` cannot be found. This has already been mentioned in Yuri Khristich's comment. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77340093/insert-image-from-drive-to-table-in-google-document-with-apps-script#comment136346575_77340093)
2. From your showing template document, it seems that the placeholder of `MY IMAGE` is put into a table cell. In this case, I'm worried that your showing script cannot be used. I think that your showing script can be used as a placeholder in the independent paragraph without a table cell. But, unfortunately, in the case of the table cell, this cannot be used.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

1. Please put a text of `<<MY IMAGE>>` to the template document. When your showing template document is modified, please replace `MY IMAGE` with `<<MY IMAGE>>`.
2. Please modify your script as follows.

   ```
   function insertImage() {
     var image   = DriveApp.getFileById('1h293aKzW97sFqzRtREHp3hO_KV8czgKI').getBlob();
     var copyId  = DriveApp.getFileById('1dY0-q_W-YO_R6WoOE6BqueN9qGFS06TPyrGWGeqChfY').makeCopy('Application'+'_2020-').getId();
     var copyBody = DocumentApp.openById(copyId).getBody();
     var position = copyBody.findText('<<MY IMAGE>>').getElement();
     if (!position) {
       throw new Error("Placeholder of '<<MY IMAGE>>' is not found.");
     }
     var para = position.getParent().asParagraph();
     var insertedImage = para.appendInlineImage(image).setHeight(100).setWidth(100);
     var styles = { [DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT]: DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT };
     insertedImage.getParent().setAttributes(styles)
     para.removeChild(position);
   }
   ```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

Comment: Awesome !!
Thank you @Tanaike. The script you modified will really help me and many friends at schools in my country. 
I have held several seminars nationally, sharing applications created with the help of scripts that you have completed in my post previously.

Comment: I have another request script modification. Can the resulting image be in the middle of the table?

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Can the resulting image be in the middle of the table?`, if my understanding of it is correct, how about replacing `var styles = { [DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT]: DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT };` to `para.getParent().setVerticalAlignment(DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER); var styles = { [DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT]: DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER };`? By this, an image is put into the center of the cell.

Comment: I have QRCode Chart ,  like this one  : https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=Siswa%201%20XII%20KGSP%201%2011%20April%202022%2014.15 . How  I can insert that QrCode Chart  in the Document, like Insert Image in this post ?  There is no file id in QRCode Chart, like file  image in drive where file id  available.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan About your new question, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, I will post my  issue in new post.