# HOW TO INSERT QRCODE INTO DOCUMENT WITH APPS SCRIPT

Tags: image, google-apps-script, qr-code

In my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77340093/insert-image-from-drive-to-table-in-google-document-with-apps-script), I can insert Image in a document, arrange Image styles and size.
Furthermore, in google spreadsheet, I use formula to convert text or Url to a QRCODE,  like this QRCODE Url  : https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chld=2&chl=sampleQRCode

I can place/insert  and view this QRCODE  in a single cell from a sheet, with formula '=IMAGE(https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chld=2&chl=sampleQRCode)'

My Question, how to insert the QRCODE Image in the Document using Apps Script?
With previous script, where I have Image in my Drive, I can find Image File ID to recognize image address and use it to run the script.

This is the script :

```
  function cetakJurnalQR() {

  var fileMasterId  = '1Qvj2iA-5iT3YRAkrkkB7lRNOr47pwS5rLQ5G8XXXXXX'
  var folderID      = "1qQZSrTugL_ZkyZ-ceGo8b6RqY2XXXXXX"

  var fotoID        = "1Bgtm96DntV5ulsWHVI-IYDEYxcXXXXXX" 
  // I want to Use QR Code to replace this Image with 'fotoID'
  // I can't find ID  for this QRCODE : https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chld=2&chl=sampleQRCode

  var image       = DriveApp.getFileById(fotoID).getBlob();
  var copyId      = DriveApp.getFileById(fileMasterId).makeCopy('NEW JOURNAL'+'_2023_').getId();
  var copyDoc     = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  var copyBody    = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

 // INSERT  QR CODE
  var position    = copyBody.findText('<QRCode>').getElement();
       if (!position) {
      throw new Error("Placeholder of '<QRCode>' is not found.");
      }    

  var para          = position.getParent().asParagraph();
  var insertedImage = para.appendInlineImage(image).setHeight(100).setWidth(100);

    para.getParent().setVerticalAlignment(DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER);  

  var styles = { [DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT]: DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER };
  
     insertedImage.getParent().setAttributes(styles)
     para.removeChild(position);
      copyDoc.saveAndClose();

 // Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion

     docblob = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 
     docblob.setName("NEW GENERATE .pdf");

      var file   = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);

   // ADDED

  var newFileId = file.getId();   
  var newFile   = DriveApp.getFileById(newFileId);    
  var docFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)

   newFile.moveTo(docFolder);

   DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);

  }
```

I want replace text   in Document with My QRCode Image.
[image: Master Document]

To

[image: Document with QRCode]

*I am greatful for any help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your showing script works fine, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var image       = DriveApp.getFileById(fotoID).getBlob();
```

#### To:

```
var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chld=2&chl=sampleQRCode").getBlob();
```

- In this modification, the blob of the image data is retrieved from your URL of `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chld=2&chl=sampleQRCode`.
- In this modification, it supposes that your showing script works fine. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replyng. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about the details of it? If your issue wasn't resolved, I apologize. At that time, can you provide more information? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill too. Thanks for your help. It's work.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.