# Inserting an Image in a Document Has An Error when the Image Extension is WEBP or Corrupt File

Tags: google-apps-script

By developing the script that I posted previously  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77340093/insert-image-from-drive-to-table-in-google-document-with-apps-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77421210/how-to-insert-qrcode-into-document-with-apps-script), I am trying to generate many documents based on the data available in the spreadsheet. The documents that I generate are documents that are not yet in the document URL list (the cell is still empty because the previous process was not successful or for other reasons).

The process of identifying empty cells in the list and generating documents one by one is not a problem until there is an image document with an extension .webp (image_name.webp ) or there is an image file but it is a corrupt file (0 bytes on the drive).

This is the script I made :

```
 function runBlankCell() {

  var ss            = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetRespon   = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses');
  var rowNo         = sheetRespon.getLastRow();
  var colJournal    = sheetRespon.getRange(9, 22, rowNo - 8, 1); // Data form response start on row number 9

  // Retrieves all data from the column containing the URL of the Journal document
  var dataKolom = colJournal.getValues();

  // Loop through column data
  for (var i = 0; i < dataKolom.length; i++) {
  // Check whether the value in the cell is empty or not
  if (dataKolom[i][0] === "") {
  // Get the appropriate line number
  var rowNumber = i + 9; // Adjust to the initial row of the data column
  
 Logger.log(rowNumber)

  // Run the function on the Empthy Row Number
  ifCellEmpthy(rowNumber);      
     }
   }
 }


 // The function to be executed on a specific Row number
 function ifCellEmpthy(rowNumber) {

 var ss            = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheetRespon   = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses');
 var fileMasterId  = "1rKa6rNPyyQWxJxhE-RBsaKjTRsnene0TKxxxxxxxx" //  Master Document ID

 // COLUMN
 var colName             = 3 ;  
 var colIDFolder         = 11 ;
 var colDescActivities   = 13 ; // Column containing descriptions of student activities
 var colFotoID           = 19 ; // The column contains ID PHOTO
 var colUrlJurnal        = 22 ; // column where the URL of the resulting document is filled in

 //  ISI  CELL  DATA 

 var name            = sheetRespon.getRange(rowNumber,colName).getValue() ;
 var iDFolder        = sheetRespon.getRange(rowNumber,colIDFolder).getValue() ;
 var descActivities  = sheetRespon.getRange(rowNumber,colDescActivities).getValue() ;
 var fotoID          = sheetRespon.getRange(rowNumber,colFotoID).getValue() ;


 let imageFile
 try{
    imageFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fotoID)
    }catch(err){

    Logger.log("Photos not submitted by students")
    }

 var image         = imageFile && imageFile.getBlob();  
 var copyId        = DriveApp.getFileById(fileMasterId).makeCopy('JURNAL PKL'+'_2024_').getId();
 var copyDoc       = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
 var copyBody      = copyDoc.getActiveSection();


 copyBody.replaceText('<<Nama_Lengkap>>', name );
 copyBody.replaceText('<<KEGIATAN PKL>>', descActivities);


 var positionFoto    = copyBody.findText('<<FOTO>>').getElement();
    if (!positionFoto) {
        throw new Error("Placeholder of '<<FOTO>>' is not found.");
       }    

 var para          = positionFoto.getParent().asParagraph();
 var insertedImage = image && para.appendInlineImage(image).setHeight(500).setWidth(400);

 var stylesFoto = { [DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT]: DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER };
  
  image && insertedImage.getParent().setAttributes(stylesFoto)
  para.removeChild(positionFoto);
  

  // Save and close the temporary document

  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  // Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion

  docblob = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 

  docblob.setName("Jurnal PKL "+name+".pdf");

  var file          = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);

  // ADDED TO FOLDER DESTINATION
  var newFileId = file.getId();   
  var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newFileId);

  //  INSERT DATA FILE URL TO FORM RESPONSE

  var urlJurnalPdf  = newFile.getUrl();

  ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses").getRange(rowNumber,colUrlJurnal).setValue(urlJurnalPdf);

  var docFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(iDFolder)

  newFile.moveTo(docFolder);

  //  Deleting temporary files

  DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
  }
```

Based on the script above, I hope for help in resolving the existing error with the solution:

1. Change the image file with the extension .webp to .jpg and process it into the document, or ignore the process of inserting the image file if it cannot be converted so that the script does not error.
2. Ignore processing corrupt files so that errors do not occur.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sample from image file with 0 byte size (corrupt) : https://drive.google.com/file/d/12CnxSUJbyY3X7BcLI4VUem1GE7ao_Pof/view

Comment: This sample from image file with .webp  extension : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lDknypH1W5sZa64RvveMLuXeP18ufHfF/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showing script, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
 let imageFile
 try{
    imageFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fotoID)
    }catch(err){

    Logger.log("Photos not submitted by students")
    }

 var image         = imageFile && imageFile.getBlob();
```

#### To:

```
let imageFile
try {
  imageFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w1000&id=${fotoID}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
} catch (err) {
  Logger.log("Photos not submitted by students")
}
var image = imageFile;
```

or

```
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w1000&id=${fotoID}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }, muteHttpExceptions: true });
var statusCode = res.getResponseCode();
if (statusCode != 200) {
  Logger.log("Photos not submitted by students");
}
var image = statusCode == 200 ? res.getBlob() : null;
```

- In this modification, the thumbnail is used.

Comment: Thank You @Tanaike. The script to ignore image with 0  byte  size,  .webp ekstension, or empthy Imaga ID runs successfully. What about the problem of image files with the webp extension? Is it possible to convert it to JPG and continue with the process of inserting it into a document?

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying. About `What about the problem of image files with the webp extension?`, in my answer, the thumbnail image is used. So, when the files can be opened with Google Drive can be used even when the movie file is used. And, when I tested my script using your webp, I confirmed that the script worked. If this was not your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan About your additional question of `Is it possible to convert it to JPG and continue with the process of inserting it into a document?`, if you want to convert the thumbnail image to JPEG format, you can use `getAs(MimeType.JPEG)`. It's like `var image = imageFile.getAs(MimeType.JPEG);` or `var image = statusCode == 200 ? res.getAs(MimeType.JPEG) : null;`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the results carefully. That's right, even though it has the  .webp extension, the document was successfully generated with the image included in it. Thanks @Tanaike . That's awesome.